# Rank-one Update to a Rank Revealing QR (RRQR) Factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-factorization

Suppose we are given an RRQR factorization for some matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $A\Pi = QR$ where $m > n$.

Is there a cheap way to update $A' = A + uv^{\top}$ given this factorization?

I am aware of how to update the QR factorization given a rank-one update, but I am unsure how to update $\Pi$ as well to guarantee the rank-revealing aspect.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a usable result for the pivoted QR decomposition, but a related class of matrix decompositions are the $UTV$ decompositions with
$$
A = U T V $$ with $U$ and $V$ being orthogonal matrices and $T$ being triangular. This decomposition has similar rank-revealing properties as pivoted QR, but there are also algorithms known for the addition and deletion of columns or rows that run in $\mathcal{O}(m n)$ . An easily accessible reference would be G. W. Stewart, "An updating algorithm for Subspace tracking". A  later reference would be Jesse L. Barlow, "Modification and Maintenance of ULV Decompositions".
If you're interested in rank-1 updates, then the classic paper 1974
"Methods for modifying Matrix Factorizations" by Gill et al. contains in section 4 an algorithm for rank-1 updates to what they call "complete orthogonal factorizations".

Comment: The update here is not an addition or deletion of columns or rows.

Comment: you're right, I've modified my reply with a proper reference for that.

Comment: With regard to the original question for the QRP decomposition, it might be worthwhile to point out, that GSL has the function gsl_linalg_QRPT_update , which does an update but will not change the permutation matrix P.